# Fazer ShellScript atuar como pipLine

Tags: bash, shell

Como posso fazer meu script conseguir atuar em um pipeLine

exemplo:

```
ls|./meuScript|grep 'Mensagem Qualquer'
```

o que './meuScript' tem que ter para  atuar  como um filtro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta que o seu script use comandos que leiam a entrada padrão e escrevam na saída padrão.

Exemplo:

Temos o script `abc-lines.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep abc | wc -l
```

Podemos usá-lo neste comando:

```
$ echo -e 'abcd\nefgh\n123abc\nxabcy\nzzz' | \
./abc-lines.sh | \
sed -r 's/(.*)/[\1]/'
```

...e o resultado será: `[3]`

Isso porque a entrada padrão dos comandos do seu script será a entrada padrão do seu script (a não ser se o comando estiver após um pipe, como o `wc` do exemplo). O mesmo vale para funções.

Se você precisa capturar a entrada padrão para manipulações mais elaboradas você pode usar o `read`. Exemplo:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read LINE
do
    echo "I read $LINE"
    # alguma mágica aqui
done
```

Tudo o que você imprimir, seja com `echo` ou qualquer outro comando, poderá ser usado por outro script na sequencia de pipes feita pelo usuário.

Atenção: Existem duas saídas STDOUT e STDERR. O pipe vai transmitir a STDOUT.

Se você quiser mandar a saída de um comando para STDERR para escapar do PIPE, faça:

```
echo "mensagem de erro" >&2
```

Se quiser fundir a STDERR com a STDOUT para *pipear* as duas, faça:

```
ls /nowhere 2>&1 | grep something
```

Comment: estava apanhando por conta de não saber o detalhe do ` read LINE`
muito obrigado.

Comment: porem quando coloco ´read LINE´ e vou usar o programa fora de um pipe ele trava

Comment: Ele não está travado, está esperando input. Ele vai ler o que vc digitar. ;-)

Comment: Exatamente isso que quis dizer, ( o travar foi no sentido de parar o processamento e esperar a entrada do usuário) 

resolvi esse problema fazendo uma verificação nos arquivos descritores 

´if [ -t 0 ]; then ...´ que verifica se o arquivo associado ao descritor de arquivo termina na janela do terminal.